# Accessing instance variable in rails and ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to ruby and rails and sometimes I still get confused between these two. I have tried to call an instance variable by adding a name of the instance variable after an object(john.name), and I hope that the result would be John. Unfortunately NoMethodError appears. So I searched for an answer and found out that you can use instance_variable_get method to do this. However, I believe that it is possible to do this in RAILS when you want to access the instance variable of an object in VIEWS.

```
class Person
    def initialize(name)
        @name = name
    end
end
john = Person.new("John")
puts john.instance_variable_get(:@name)
=> John
puts john.name
=> NoMethodError
```

Comment: You can't access instance variable directly. Variables are generally part of something, confined within a method or class, say. But to get its value, you have it set it to a method or use `attr_accessor`. Below two answers show you how.

Comment: Ruby is simple. All an object exposes are methods. You can't access instance variables from outside directly.

Comment: @arjun, You don't need an accessor: `class C; def initialize; @x = 1; end; end; C.new.instance_variable_get(:@x) #=> 1`.

Comment: Assuming that the variable appears once in the code. But generally variables are modified many times and I believe, that the proper way is to define it in a class method and call that instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `attr_reader` to read the value of an instance variable

```
class Person
  attr_reader :name

  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end
end

john = Person.new("John")
john.name #=> "John"
```

`attr_reader` adds a getter method to the class, in this case

```
def name
  @name
end
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the method to access your instance variable.

```
class Person
  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end

  def name
    @name
  end
end
```

Or you can simply add attr_accessor which will set getter and setter methods

```
class Person
  attr_accessor :name

  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end
end
```